# What are the practical limits of the "Control Kinetic Energy" Power?

Tags: powers, heroes-unlimited

The game of Heroes Unlimited 2E that I'm currently playing in has a hero power that is available to Superheroes called "Control Kinetic Energy." The description for the power states that it can do the following:

- Null Movement Field (Prevent objects entering a certain radius from moving, effectively stopping them. Can be applied to specific objects as well).
- Increase Movement (Make specific Objects such as bullets, moving people, etc. move faster)
- Deflect Kinetic Energy (Can drain the kinetic energy from an attack while reflecting that energy back on its source)

Among these powers which are listed in the book:

1. What are the limits of the power
2. What level of fine control can you exercise with it?

Comment: However, a question about the Control Kinetic Energy power's limits and the amount of fine control the user can exercise with the power may be acceptable (and also might spur the imagination).

Answer (score 1):

In concrete terms, the application of Control Kinetic Energy stems from what is allowed as a target.

I'll use the null movement option as an example.

**Targeted Objects**

You can directly target items or people. You are allowed to target anything in range which is visible.  "Visible" is going to be the key limitations. Some things you can't do:

- Stop someone's heart (because a heart is obscured by a body)
- Stop a nano-bot from destroying something (because it is too small to see)

This power is also only applicable to objects. Examples of things you couldn't do:

- Prevent exposure to radiation (because radiation is energy, not matter)

**Fields**

If you create the field, there really is no fine control - everything entering the field is hampered.  Thus, you couldn't stop enemy bullets while allowing a partner to lob you an item.

The rules don't make it clear if fields can only influence visible objects. For example, could you use a null field to prevent poisonous gases from reaching you? Ask the GM on this one.

Comment: Those are the technical limits. I suspect the question is not a "read the book to me" question though, and is looking for those translated into practical "what's the range of stuff it can do" limits.

Comment: As an example, A firing pin is a device present in almost every gun or explosive that triggers the payload, normally due to either striking or puncturing, which triggers an explosive that propels shrapnel or metal slugs. If someone uses null movement on the firing pin of a device, theoretically you could prevent any gun from firing, any grenade from exploding, or any landmine from triggering.

Similarly, you could jolt an explosive such as an RPG with an abrupt change in kinetic energy to force the grenade to trigger the detonator and explode.